# AJAX shared JS and PHP processing files

Tags: php, ajax

I have the same JS and processing PHP files working in many folders.  Trying to put them in a common folder to call from anywhere for modular code.

• calling the JS from my index.html works OK;

•• but putting the processing PHP file in the common folder does not.

Is there a way to make indirect calls, or something better?

Comment: If you show us your file and folder structure and your code, we will most likely be able to help. Without that, we would just be guessing. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Working ~ my error was in the path.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

JS script was working when embedded in the html files

but did NOT work when called as an external .js file.

Solved by embedding JS script in the file with shared PHP functions.

Now fully modular!